# Deedle in dotnet interactive

Tags: f#, deedle, dotnet-interactive

## Context

If I enter the following:

```ml
#r "nuget:Deedle"
#r "nuget:FSharp.Charting"

open System
open Deedle
open FSharp.Charting

let dates = [ 
    DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
    DateTime(2013, 1, 4);
    DateTime(2013, 1, 8); ]

let values = [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]

let first = Series(dates, values)
```

which are the first few steps from the following:

https://fslab.org/Deedle/tutorial.html

into an F# [dotnet interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive) notebook, `first` doesn't appear to render anything:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to get Deedle values to render nicely in dotnet interactive?

Answer (score 2):

I get decent looking output if I set the format to plain text:

```ml
let first = Series(dates, values)

Formatter.SetPreferredMimeTypesFor(typeof<obj>, "text/plain")
Formatter.Register(fun (x:obj) (writer: TextWriter) -> fprintfn writer "%120A" x )

first
```

Output is:

```
series [ 1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM => 10; 1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM => 20; 1/8/2013 12:00:00 AM => 30]
```

You can try it out [here](https://github.com/brianberns/DeedleNotebook/blob/main/Notebook.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

See the following project:

https://github.com/WalternativE/Deedle.DotNet.Interactive.Extension

Note that it currently appears to require the *insiders* version of the vscode .NET Interactive plugin.

Comment: Even better, it doesn't require _insiders_ version anymore